# MySQL Foreign Key Error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to create a database and connect it with two database. But I don't know when i create the Foreign Key to the second database (time_shift table) it always result error 150;

Here is the structure of table `outlet`:
[image: Table Outlet]

And this is structure of table `time_shift`:
[image: Table time_shift]

And this the query to create new table `tide_cart`:

```
create table `tide_chart` (
    `id` int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
    `date` date null,
    `outletId` int(11) not null,
    `timeShiftId` int(11) not null,
    `value` varchar(255) not null,

    unique (`date`, `outletId`, `timeShiftId`),
    foreign key (`outletId`) references `outlet`(`id`) 
        ON update cascade ON delete cascade,
    foreign key (`timeShiftId`) references `time_shift`(`id`) 
        ON update cascade ON delete cascade
) engine=innoDB;
```

Please explain to me, why i get error when try to make foreign key connect to table `time_shift`?

---

Update: add dump export structure table for `outlet` and `time_shift`:

```
CREATE TABLE `outlet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ; 

  CREATE TABLE `time_shift` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `time_start` time NOT NULL,
   `time_end` time NOT NULL,
   `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `ref_area` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `ref_area` (`ref_area`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Comment: Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements for outlet and time_shift?

Comment: @TheVedge I dump export structure of table :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the InnoDB engine for your tables. time_shift is using MyISAM.

Comment: Yes, after you told me about exporting the table structure. I realized the `time_shift` table use `MyISAM` @_@. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. Most of the time I see this error, it's a MyISAM table, or a type mismatch between the foreign key and the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You must define indexes for `outletId` and `timeShiftId` (either `UNIQUE` or `KEY` as needed) in order to be able to create a foreign key using that field.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, but like i said. Creating Foreign Key for `outletId` is success but failure for `timeShiftId`. And they both use similar query. @_@